# SwiftUI - Objc @protocol delgate function usage

Tags: objective-c, swiftui

I cannot figure how to implement an ObjC library delegate/protocol function in a SwifUI view/app.

It works well in an ObjC or swift application

Here is the code and explanation (I simplified so there may be some typo)

In the ObC library it is implemented like this

MyClass.h from ObjC library

```
    @protocol CustomDelegate <NSObject>

    - (void)endEvent:(BOOL) done;

    @end
```

MyClass.h is imported in bridging.h declared in ObjectiveC-bridging-header settings

In a swift application we do this and it works.
The delegate ObjC library function endEvent is well called

ViewController.swift

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var myclass = Myclass()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myclass.setDelegate(self)
    }


    //Delegate methods
    override func endEvent(done:Bool) {
        print("done \(done)")
    }

}
```

Internally in the Objc library we store the caller and check that the protocol function is implemented in it

```
    -(void) SetDelegate:(id)delegate
    {
        myDelegate = delegate;
    }


    -(void)notifyEndEvent
    {
        if (myDelegate == nil)
            return;
    
        // check caller implemented the delegate function and if so call it
        if (([myDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(endEvent: done:)]) {
            [myDelegate endEvent:done];
        } else {
            printf("endEvent not implemented by the caller\n"); 
        }
    }   
}
```

How can I do the same in Switfui view ?
If I do as shown below it doesn't work because in the ObjC library the respondsToSelector function shown above return false

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    
    @State var myclass = Myclass()

    private func start() {
        myclass.setDelegate(self)
    }

    func endEvent(sender: Myclass , endEvent done:Bool) {
        print("endEvent \(done)")
    }

       
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In any case if you declare a class as *source of truth* in a SwiftUI view you have to mark it as `@StateObject`. And a SwiftUI view is not a controller. A better way to handle the delegate is a view model (another class conforming to `@ObservableObject`) and `@Publish` the changes. It can be even a subclass of `NSObject`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It leads me to the solution I post below. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Vadian comments I figured out how to do
You have to declare and use your function in a specific class
This way the objc callback are well called

Declare your class that implements you objc library code and delegate

```
class MyClassModel: ObservableObject{

    var myclass = Myclass()
    
    func start(){
        myclass.setDelegate(self)
    ...
    }
    
    @objc func endEvent(done:Bool) {
        print("endEvent \(done)")
    }

}
```

Another way with NSObject

```
class MyClassModel2 : NSObject
{
    var myclass = Myclass()
    
    func start(){
       myclass.setDelegate(self)
       ...
    }
    
    @objc func endEvent(done:Bool) {
        print("endEvent \(done)")
    }
}
```

Use it in your view

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var myClassModel = MyClassModel()
    @State var myClassModel2 = MyClassModel2()

    myClassModel.start()
    myClassModel2.start()
}
```